# Everything is upload in the database except image

Tags: php, sql-server, image, path, insert

I want to upload the image to this folder called roomPhoto. Then from there i want the sql server database name imagepath to store the path instead of the image itself. Can someone help me with this?

```
session_start();
include "../../lib/mssql.connect.php";

    $target = "roomPhoto/";
    $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['imagepath']);

    $params = array($_POST['xone'],$_POST['yone'], $_POST['xtwo'], $_POST['ytwo'], $_POST['venue'] , $_POST['description'] , $_POST['roomlevel'], ( $_FILES['photo']['imagepath']));
    $sql = "INSERT INTO map(x1, y1, x2, y2, venue, description, roomLevel, imagepath)
          VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params);
    echo "Account had been successfully created";
```

Comment: Where is your HTML form? It looks like you're missing `enctype`.

Comment: You need to add `move_uploaded_file` for moving in particular folder. It seems that you have not used it. even if the name is name is saved and there won't be any image in folder and broken image will be shown

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to not store image in database.
This is comment but i am not able for that.

Efficient way to do is:

Only save image name  in database and upload image in specific folder using [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php).

For display image, you will get image name from query...append that in your folder path and just set it to

```
<img src="PATH_HERE">
```